# How to add more visible images to my JS loop

Tags: javascript

I am creating an image carousel and trying to add more than one visible image at a time, next to each other - inline..  I thought this would be an easy task but it's proving to be a hassle.

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 2
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "inline-block";
    // dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

I thought I would just be able to modify the slide index or the for loop but the code is simply not working.. As of now, the code will cycle through individually but I cannot get any other images to show up during a transition.. It would be nice to have at least three images next to each other during the slideshow and then transition to another three images.

Comment: If you initialize `slideIndex` at `-1`, you won't need to constantly offset using `slideIndex-1`.

Answer (score 1):

Why it is happened?
This block hide all images.

```
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
   slides[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

This block shows only one

```
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 2}
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "inline-block";
```

after the timeout all one visible image will be hidden again, and only one will be opened.

If you to show more images try

```
slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex> slides.length) {slideIndex = 2}
for (i = 0; i < slideIndex; i++) {
  slides[slideIndex-i].style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

If you to show more images and every time different images try this

```
var countOfShownimages = 3;

slideIndex++;
if (slideIndex < countOfShownimages || slideIndex > slides.length) { 
  slideIndex = countOfShownimages;
}

for (i = slideIndex - countOfShownimages; i < slideIndex; i++) {
  slides[i].style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that displays a slide is:

```
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "inline-block";
```

So to run that more than once you can use a `for` loop. Starting from `0`, offset `slideIndex` until you've displayed all of the slides that you wish. You can use `% slides.length` in order to make the indexes "wrap around" to the front of the array when it reaches the end.

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  slides[(slideIndex-1 + i) % slides.length].style.display = "inline-block";
}
```

Comment: Aha.. Well, both of these work but when the slideshow tries to loop from the last div I receive an error of: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Comment: @smck I forgot about that part. I've updated so that the index wraps around to the front of the array when it reaches the end.